# Solving inequality issue between bound variables and tokens, when number of bound variables is dynamic. (PDO/PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

**Context:**

I am attempting to update a record with a set of values in a MySQL database using the usual UPDATE syntax, via PDO method of binding tokens to data.

**The Problem:**

The number of fields to be updated is dynamic, and is adjusted depending on what data has been POSTed to the page. Using an `if(isset($_POST[]))` to filter out updates to fields which may already have data in, but I don't want to be overwritten by empty data.

This means that the number of tokens I am creating varies, but my syntax for binding data to the tokens is static, and I'm not sure how to adjust it.

This of course results in: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

**My Code:**

Please note that $data is an array of all the column names in my database. It is also the set of name attributes of the variables that may be posted, such that $_POST[x] should be updated to the column x in a given record, and x is a member of $data.

```
$sql_b =    "UPDATE `temp_data` SET ";  
            foreach($data as $value)
            {
            if(isset($_POST[$value]))
            $sql_b .="$value = :$value, ";
            }

            $sql_b = rtrim($sql_b,', ');    
            $sql_b .=" WHERE UID = '$uid'";

try     
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db01', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_b);

foreach($data as $value)
{
$stmt->bindParam(":$value", $_POST[$value]);
}

$stmt->bindParam(":sv_215_hidden", $_POST[sv_215_hidden]);
$stmt->bindParam(":sv_216_hidden", $_POST[sv_216_hidden]);

$stmt->execute();
```

# Affected Rows?
      echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

**To highlight the problem areas of this:**

This code:

```
foreach($data as $value)
            {
            if(isset($_POST[$value]))
            $sql_b .="$value = :$value, ";
            }
```

Creates a subset of possible UPDATE requests

Where as this code:

```
foreach($data as $value)
{
$stmt->bindParam(":$value", $_POST[$value]);
}
```

Always creates a full set of bindings between all possible tokens.

**Central Question:**

How can I adjust the number of bindings to match only the fields being updated?

Comment: Why can't you re-use `if(isset($_POST[$value]))` in the bindParam statement?

Comment: I had to do something similar but I just build up a where clause string and a corresponding `$params` array with my bound variables. Then I pass the array into execute and make sure it has variables in it so I don't put just a WHERE inside of the query.

Comment: @andrewsi ...I... I don't know *facepalm*, ok I was over thinking this one. Let me go see if that works (it seems like it should)

Comment: @andrewsi ...yes, that works fine. I don't know how I didn;t think of that, I can't even claim it's late as I just started work. :) Hah, well, thanks for that - want to write up a quick solution so I can mark you up? Not that too many people will find this useful.

Comment: @Gideon - sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes. Or one more coffee....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already there; you're checking to see what fields are set when you generate the SQL statement:

```
foreach($data as $value)
        {
        if(isset($_POST[$value]))
        $sql_b .="$value = :$value, ";
        }
```

So you can use the exact same logic when you're calling `bindParam()`:

```
foreach($data as $value)
        {
        if(isset($_POST[$value]))
        $stmt->bindParam(":$value", $_POST[$value]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a couple of extra steps:

```
$keys = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foobar');
$updates = array();
$bound = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
    if (isset($_POST[$key])){
        $updates[] = $key . '= :' . $key;
        $bound[':' . $key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET ' . implode(',', $updates) . ' WHERE etc'; //add your where clause
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($bound);
```

In other words, you can pass an array of bound parameters to PDOStatement::execute rather than binding them individually beforehand; and doing things as above makes sure that the bound parameters match what's in your SQL.